# How to run a jar file that used to be run with appletviewer under macOS Monterey?

Tags: java, macos-monterey

Forgive me for asking a potentially stupid question, but I am not a java programmer, so ... here goes:

I've got a jar file that I used to run using appletviewer under macOS.
The accompanying HTML file contains these lines:

```
    <applet code="Texture.class" archive="texture.jar" width=800 height=800>
    <param name="datafile" value="cube1.txt">
    <param name="perspective" value="false">
    </applet>
```

Using `jar xf texture.jar`, I determined that the MANIFEST.MF file does not contain a MainClass.
I have tried guessing the main class running `java -cp texture.jar Texture.class` and other tries, but maybe that was in vain because there is no main class?
Also, I have, naturally, googled a lot, to no avail.

As far as I can see, appletviewer is deprecated.
Unfortunately, I don't have the Java source code.

So, does anybody know if/how I can still run this code?

Thanks a lot in advance for any hints, suggestions, or insights.

Comment: You could create a new project, which uses the jar as a library dependency, if you're lucky, the code is written well and you don't need to show the `Applet` class, otherwise it becomes a lot more difficult

Answer (score 2):

That's not enough; applets have some frameworky bits that the app itself simply does not have, but needs to run. You either need a browser, or an app called `appletviewer` that used to ship with JDKs but probably no longer does.

Find the oldest JRE/JDK you can find out there and pray that it includes an app called `appletviewer`. If you can't find one, then you **must** have the sources to this app and know a little bit of java and you can fix this (pretty much make a JPanel in a JFrame and render the applet in that; presumably the applet doesn't interact with browser specific API, as very few applets ever did that).

If you don't have that skillset I'm not aware of any automated way to do this.

NB: There *is no* main class; the applet runner itself is the main class. The first code that runs from that actual app is `Texture.class` – it doesn't have a `main` method, nothing in that jar would.